# Set random points within a given distance of a known street network

Tags: qgis, r, point, distance, network

I have a street network with a known ditance of 39735 km. Now my goal is to set a point every 200 km on this street network, so that there will be exactly 198 points generated. The distance of 200 km should be the traveld distance not the arial line.

Has anybody an idea how to do that in either in QGIS or in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done for a general street network. Consider a street network of 40,000 1km roads that all branch from a single point (a very unlikely network, but extremes serve to illustrate the point). No point on that network is more than 2km from any other point, so its impossible to put points 200km apart although there is 40,000 km of street. So a necessary requirement is that your network has a diameter (in the graph theory sense of the shortest maximum distance between any two points) of at least 200 km.

But its worse. If you want each point to be 200km from its nearest neighbour (which I think you are asking, clarification would help) then each point can exclude a huge chunk of the network - ie everything within 200km - and that could be a lot more than 200km of linear street. That eventually means you aren't going to be able to place all the points you want.

So unless your street network has a very particular form, you will struggle to set points according to your requirements. Its easy if your network is a single straight line, for example...

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have to find another way. I will try to extract different corridors that are a single lines and try to put points on them.